# Get product name from store not from admin

Tags: magento-1.9, programmatically, programming

I am working on product collection query which is filtered from different root categories. My products are coming correctly but my product name is coming from admin section not from store section.

> $collection->addAttributeToSelect(array('entity_id','name','description','created_at','price','status','parent_id'))
>
> ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
>   ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
>   ->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => '%'.$search_product.'%'));
>
> $conditions = array();
>         foreach ($category_filters_ids as $categoryId)      {
>               if (is_numeric($categoryId)) { $conditions[] = "{{table}}.category_id = $categoryId"; } }
>
> $collection->distinct(true)
>   ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', null, 'product_id = entity_id', implode(" OR ", $conditions), 'inner');

Comment: have  you tried the code on frontend or  a  sciprt

Comment: In my script....

Comment: please show your sciprt code and how  have includer mage.php and call the magento store